# Relationship between VC dimension and degrees of freedom

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, vc-dimension

I'm studying machine learning and I feel there is a strong relationship between the concept of VC dimension and the more classical (statistical) concept of degrees of freedom.

Can anyone explain such a connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yaser Abu-Mostafa --- Learning with data

> Degrees of freedom are an abstraction of the effective number of parameters. The effective number is based on how many [dichotomies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomy) one can get, rather than how many real-valued parameters are used. In the case of 2-dimensional perceptron, one can think of slope and intercept (plus a binary degree of freedom for which region goes to +1), or one can think of 3 parameters w_0,w_1,w_2 (though the weights can be simultaneously scaled up or down without affecting the resulting hypothesis). The degrees of freedom, however, are 3 because we have the flexibility to shatter 3 points, not because of one way or another of counting the number of parameters.

[image: 2-d perceptron]

Comment: It looks like you're quoting a resource with this answer, could you please attribute it to its original source?

Comment: Yes, of course. I will add the source as soon as I will be in front of my pc!

Comment: Source: http://book.caltech.edu/bookforum/showthread.php?t=4251